# Push message from Java with Spring 4 WebSocket

Tags: java, spring, websocket, spring-4, spring-websocket

I'd like to push messages from Java to WebSocket clients. I've successfully made a js client send to the server and receive a message back on 2 js clients, so the client side code works fine.

My issue is that I'd like to initiate a send when events occur within the Java app. So for example every time 10 orders have been placed send a message to all subscribed clients. Is this possible?

My current config:

```
<websocket:message-broker application-destination-prefix="/app">
   <websocket:stomp-endpoint path="/hello">
        <websocket:sockjs/>
   </websocket:stomp-endpoint>
   <websocket:simple-broker prefix="/topic"/>
</websocket:message-broker>

@Controller
public class MessageController {
    @MessageMapping("/hello")
    @SendTo("/topic/greetings")
    public Greeting greeting() throws Exception {
       return new Greeting("Hello world");
    }
}
```

What I'd like to be able to do is something like this:

```
public class OrderManager {
    @Autowired MessageController messageController;
    int orderCount = 0;

    public void processOrder(Order o) {
        orderCount++;
        if(orderCount % 10 == 0)
            messageController.greeting();
    }
}
```

and all subscribed clients to the websocket receive a message.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use the `SimpMessagingTemplate.` It's automatically registered.  Just `autowire` it in any Spring bean you want.

```
@Autowired
private SimpMessagingTemplate template;
...
this.template.convertAndSend("/topic/greetings", text);
```

Comment: I implemented your approach and now I get an exception 'Failed to start bean subProtocolWebSocketHandler'. I have created a post about it. Please take a look if you can. Thanks. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37638396/getting-a-failed-to-start-bean-subprotocolwebsockethandler-exception-while-try

Comment: hi, i have done the same process but my websocket is not called, i dont have any error.